# IndexedSlicesQuery with multiple row keys

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to achieve the following query in hector

SELECT * FROM column_family WHERE row_keys IN (List) AND indexed_col BETWEEN x AND y

I am not able to find any API which can do this. I am using hector 1.01 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with [cql3](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html) which has support for this

```
SELECT * FROM column_family WHERE row_keys IN (List) AND indexed_col >= x AND  index_col <= y;
```

and [datastax java driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) which has good support for cql3.